# TextBox cssclass not taking effect when viewed in IE but fine in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a textbox that I set the cssclass property to the name of my class that I want used.

Here is the class

```
.summaryfieldcolor
{
     background-color:#ffcc99;
}
```

However, this color is not shown in IE, but it works fine in Chrome.
Is there an IE hack for this?

[update 3/6/2014 720am]
IE version 9
Example

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbTotalValue" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" CssClass="summaryfieldcolor"></asp:TextBox>
```

Well, shucks...tried it again and its working now.  Not sure what was going on and why it wasnt working yesterday.  What I just tried was putting the class definition in the page itself, and it worked, then I put it back in the css file, and that worked too. Ok, so disregard.

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well and maybe a fiddle?

Comment: IE browser versions have some bugs when it comes to rendering css. knowing your IE version could help to test. And its better if you can post the code snippet

Comment: I tried this in IE11 and it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/D4BsP/4/

Comment: Since you tagged it asp.net I'm assuming your HTML is generated. Are there any inline styling applied or other style rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that this IE setting:

Tools >> Internet Options >> Browsing history Settings

...is set to "Every time I visit the webpage" rather than "Automatically" when you are doing dev work that involves CSS changes.

Comment: I bet thats what it was.  I had it set to that to test another issue I was dealing user authentication, but didnt set it back to "Every time"

Answer (score 0):

Use web safe colors.

[web safe color palette](http://www.techbomb.com/websafe/)

Comment: what is your IE version?

Comment: I'm not referring to IE, I'm saying the link you provided includes web safe colors, and one of those colors is #ffcc99. Basically, OP is already using a web safe color.